# find element by id selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

In selenium when I search for an id or an id in an xpath, I am instantly met with a syntax error. For example, if I run

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="select-dance"]/option[2]").click()
```

I immediately get an error

```
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="select-dance"]/option[2]").click()
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried saving "select-dance" to a variable and then putting that variable in, but that does not help either.

Comment: Use different quote: `'//*[@id="select-dance"]/option[2]'`

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

...implies that the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which you have adapted have a **Syntax error**.

You have to either provide the entire *XPath* within double quotes (i.e. `"..."`) and the attribute values within single quotes (i.e. `'...'`) as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='select-dance']/option[2]").click()
```

Or you have to provide the entire *XPath* within single quotes (i.e. `'...'`) and the attribute values within double quotes (i.e. `"..."`) as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select-dance"]/option[2]').click()
```